# Prevent related records being updated in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity (Skill) which has a relationship to another entity (Game):

```
    public class Skill
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser TeamMember { get; set; }
    public int SkillPoints1 { get; set; }
    public int SkillPoints2 { get; set; }
    public int SkillPoints3 { get; set; }
    public int SkillPoints4 { get; set; }
    public int SkillPoints5 { get; set; }
    public bool Spectator { get; set; }
    public Skillset SelectedSkillNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The Game entity also has related entities:

```
    public class Game
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { set; get; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public GameState GameState { get; set; }
    public virtual Team GameTeamMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser GameOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Backlog> ProductBacklog { get; set; }
```

At some point, I'm loading in the "Skills" for a particular Game, so I have to include the game record in order to return the Skill records:

```
List<Skill> allSkillsets = _context.Skills.Include(x => x.Game).Where(x => x.Game.Id == gameId).Include(x => x.TeamMember).ToList();
```

However, when I'm looping through these records to update some of the properties, EF tries to update the "Game" record as well:

```
                foreach (Skill player in allSkillsets)
            {
                try
            {
                player.SkillPoints1 = player.SelectedSkillNumber == Skillset.Skill1 ? 5 : boost_skillset1_by + 1;
                player.SkillPoints2 = player.SelectedSkillNumber == Skillset.Skill2 ? 5 : boost_skillset2_by + 1;
                player.SkillPoints3 = player.SelectedSkillNumber == Skillset.Skill3 ? 5 : boost_skillset3_by + 1;
                player.SkillPoints4 = player.SelectedSkillNumber == Skillset.Skill4 ? 5 : boost_skillset4_by + 1;
                player.SkillPoints5 = player.SelectedSkillNumber == Skillset.Skill5 ? 5 : boost_skillset5_by + 1;

                //_context.Entry(player.Game).State = EntityState.Detached;
                _context.Entry(player.Game).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                _context.Skills.Attach(player);
                _context.Entry(player).Property(x => x.SkillPoints1).IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(player).Property(x => x.SkillPoints2).IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(player).Property(x => x.SkillPoints3).IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(player).Property(x => x.SkillPoints4).IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(player).Property(x => x.SkillPoints5).IsModified = true;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                _logger.LogErrorWithObject("Could not write backlog item to database", "UpdatePlayerSkills", player);
                throw;
            }
```

Because the "Game" entity doesn't have all of it's related entities loaded in (e.g. ProductBacklog), the update wipes out all of these records.
Is there a way I can just update the 5 properties in the Skill record, without also updating it's related Game record?

I've also tried setting Game to null, but then this removes the Id in the foreign key column

Comment: Why are you trying to re-attach Skills to the DbContext? If you load skills and related entities then modify the skill properties allowing EF's change tracking to work as intended you should find that just those properties that change are being updated. I suspect that some additional steps not outlined here to detach entities leading to working with disconnected entity sets is causing your issue. Detached entities need special care, detached entity graphs (relationships) even more so. Basically avoid them until that cost is justified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF core ignore navigational property on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955234/ef-core-ignore-navigational-property-on-save)